# How to use Flink to implement aggregate operations on non-keyed data streams?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep

I want to implement the following case :

```
 1. select count(1) from user; 
 
 2. select count(distinct uid) from user;
```

However, aggregation operations cannot be used for non-keyed streams.

A non-keyed stream cannot use keyed state,I don't know what to do, can someone help me, thank you!

You can do this using the Table API, but I was wondering how to do this in the DataSteam API.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Table API is the recommended approach. You are likely to do more work and arrive at a less performant solution by using the DataStream API.

However, to answer your question:

In both cases, if you want to use the DataStream API and don't care about doing things in parallel, you could key the stream by a constant and then use keyed state.

To parallelize the `count(1)` case, you can key the stream by *something* in order to partition the stream. Then in a set of parallel counting tasks you can count mini-batches, and send batch count updates (as a changelog stream) downstream to a single instance of a summing-up/reporting task. Or you could build a solution using [non-keyed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#operator-state).

To parallelize the `count(distinct user)` case you could model your solution on the approach implemented in the Table API -- see [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/tuning/#split-distinct-aggregation). In a nutshell, it works by transforming `select count(distinct uid) from user` into

```sql
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) as cnt
    FROM T
    GROUP BY MOD(HASH_CODE(uid), 1024)
)
```